# formula field to show Primary Contact Name on Account Object

Tags: formula-field, account, contact

In Contact Object I have Primary_Contact__c checkbox field. If this field is checked then on the Account object primary contact name should display in a Primary_Contact_Name__c field on Account.

Way better If there is a way to do by Formula field

Thanks!

Comment: Not possible using just a formula field, but you could create a custom text field on Account and have it populated using a Process on Contact.

Comment: could you explain more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a text field on Account: Primary_Contact_Name__c
2. Create a process using Process Builder, have it start when a Contact has been created or updated
3. Add criteria: Primary_Contact__c = true
4. Add an immediate action: update your Primary_Contact_Name__c field on Account with the Name of your Contact

Setting a Contact as primary contact will now update your Account accordingly.